# We should put complex parsing logic in Athena or use Glue

Tags: etl, aws-glue, amazon-athena, system-design

We have fixed length format file in S3. We want to create Athena Table after converting it to Parque. We have around 50-60 different such files

Currently I could think of two Approach:

1. Put fixed length parsing logic in Athena Table creation script.
2. Create Glue job which will parse it and create Parque files then
   create Athena table on that

**Approach-1:**
 Though, it may have minimal code, but this will be in create table script. We are using Teraform to create 
 Infra, so parsing logic(Regex or Grok pattern) would be part of infra, I am skeptical to put logic in infra code.

**Approach-2:**
 This will be Glue job written using Spark, it will be flexible to parse fixed length file, we could write reusable code for fixed length format to use for all different files. Logic to parse would be with developers. Athena will have external table on Glue job's output location.Infra code would contain only create statement.

Could you please provide your views.

Comment: You don't want to leverage Glue custom classifiers https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-classifier.html ?

Comment: forgot to mention we have tried Glue classifier also, but with our current Teraform version, we are uanle to create classifier. so skipped that approach.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to go with Approach #2. Using spark's readfile method, you can read most of fix length format files and convert them to parquet. You may do validations or quick transformation before saving in parquet if needed.